# Check if scanner contains anything inside while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, wait

How can I check whether input is available from a `Scanner` without risking blocking?

Consider the method below, for example.  In each loop iteration it should accept user input if there is any, but proceed without input if none has been entered.  Instead, `reader.nextLine()` waits for the user to input a a line before proceeding.

```
public void creatureCombate() {

    while (true) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = reader.nextLine();

        wait(1);
        System.out.println("Wolf attacks");

        if(userInput.equals("hit")){
            System.out.println("hit wolf");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Tries again");  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: Hmm is it nessesary to create a new Scaner Object every time the loop executes? And as @JoeC pointed, why is it a problem in your case? I don't see a problem in the code above?

Comment: kindly provide more detail about the problem

Comment: Instead of `reader.nextLine()`, check `reader.hasNextLine()` and only call `nextLine()` if it's true.  This is because `nextLine()` will block program execution until a "line" has been input

Comment: `this.wait()` is not the method you're looking for.  Try `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: @Gus [`hasNextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--) will block too: *This method may block while waiting for input.*

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot *"proceed without input if none has been entered"*, since all `nextXxx()` and `hasNextXxx()` methods are blocking.

If you want code to execute (e.g. wolf attacks) while waiting for input, you need multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple threads and make the `main thread` wait until `input` one is finished or timed out, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10) {
        Runnable inputThread = () -> {
            scanner.reset();
            System.out.println("Enter input");
            try{
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                input.add(line);
            }catch(Exception e){}
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(inputThread);
        t.start();

        Thread.currentThread().join(10000);
        t.interrupt();

        if(input.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Nothing enteresd");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Entered :" + input.get(0));  
            input.clear();
        }
        count++;
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```